# In Java currency representation, what are the pros and cons of using a long/short mantissa/exponent pattern over a double/epsilon pattern

Tags: java, floating-point, currency

Let me begin this question by stating that for the type of high performance application we are developing, BigDecimal is unacceptably slow. This cannot be compromised on.

In our domain, we will be representing values up to around 100,000,000 with varying levels of precision (in the most esoteric cases we have found so far, this might be six decimal places).

Given that, I see two ways of representing currency information at an arbitrary precision. The first is to follow a pattern similar to that described in [JSR-354](http://java.net/projects/javamoney/pages/Implementation) where a long represents the mantissa of a value, and a short (or an int) represents the exponent. In this case, a value of 12345.6789 would be internally represented as

```
long mantissa = 123456789L;
short exponent = -4;
```

With this, we can represent 18 figures at any precision we choose (9223372036854775807 being 19 figures)

The second is the use a double to represent the value, and use an epsilon to round away any error introduced by performing calculations on floating point numbers. Based on my understanding of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and some experimentation, I believe that we can represent 17 figures at any precision chosen. If we use a fixed epsilon, we can represent values up to 99999999999.999999 at our expected requirement of six maximum decimal places, with our epsilon able to round away any error introduced.

---

I'm not sure that either of these patterns can be considered "best" for the domain we are working  in.

A long/short pattern requires us to implement some position shifting logic if we need to perform operations on two values with different precision (this will be required). I think, but haven't confirmed, that this will make it slower than using double/epsilon for certain operations. On the other hand, using a double/epsilon introduces a small overhead on every calculation to perform the rounding.

Both can be extended to give a larger number of digits if required - JSR-354 mentions a long/long/int implementation which gives up to 37 digits at arbitrary precision. [This paper](http://web.mit.edu/tabbott/Public/quaddouble-debian/qd-2.3.4-old/docs/qd.pdf) describes a C++ implementation of double-double and quad-double types.

I've been unable to find any discussion over the advantages/disadvantages of one of the other which hasn't immediately descended into "Never Use Floating Point For Currency" without any particular justification - a mantra I agree with if performance is not a primary concern, but in this case, I'm less sure.

Comment: How confident are you about six decimal places being sufficient forever?  If very confident, have you considered getting rid of the exponent for internal calculations by shifting everything by a factor of `10^6`?  That is, instead of dealing with $123.456789, you deal with 123456789 micro-dollars.  I'm not sure if this is appropriate for your use-case though.

Comment: Right now, not 100%, but on the other hand I've realised that this means I can't really have a fixed epsilon without being 100% sure, which gives four possible options - mantissa/exponent and double/epsilon, both with either fixed exponent/epsilon or variable exponent/epsilon. I think I'll try to run some performance tests and see if there is a significant difference, plus harass our analysts to deliver their final specs.

Comment: I don't understand your concern in performance. AFAIK, Java is not supposed to be used for time-critical systems and therefore your approach might suffer from unnecessary micro-optimization. Are you really sure that BigDecimal will bottleneck your system? Just curious :)

Comment: Yes, for example take a look at [this blog post](http://azagorneanu.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/javamathbigdecimal-performance.html) which suggests that BigDecimal is around 150 times slower than floating point calculations, which roughly tallies with our internal testing. Not sure where you get the impression that "Java is not supposed to be used for time critical systems" - I know of many systems in production deployment with their critical paths measured in microseconds or single digit milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure that either of these patterns can be considered "best" for the domain we are working in.

Well you haven't mentioned what the domain is so it is hard to comment on that.

However a lot of finance-related systems are governed by the general rules of accounting.  These are clear on how financial calculations should be performed, and floating point is not acceptable.

If your domain is covered by the rules of accounting, then using floating point is really not an option.

If not, then you need to do a mathematical analysis to determine if the imprecision that is inherent in floating point is going to make a difference to the results of your computations.  Simply using a wider floating point type is not a good answer ... unless you've "done the math" to place error bounds on the result of the computation.

Or avoid the analysis and just use a scaled `long` or `BigDecimal`.  (But note that with scaled `long` you need to consider the issue of overflow / underflow.)

---

If you have "done the math" and you are not restricted by the rules of accounting (or some such) then:

- Floating point types will be easier to use, cos you don't have to mess around with a scale factor when you do arithmetic.  (Even if the scale factor is implicit, it needs to be taken into account ...)
- Floating point types will "just work" with standard library methods; e.g. the `Math` static methods.
- Floating point code will be more readable, and less prone to programming logic errors.
- Floating point types are inexact ... but if you've done the math *correctly*, that doesn't matter.  (A complete mathematical analysis will tell you if the errors build up during a calculation to the point where they cause the result to be inaccurate.)

Performance ... hard to say.  It probably depends on the actual calculations.  My advice would be to code the critical calculations both ways and carefully benchmark them.

Comment: The domain is "accurate representation and calculation of numbers up to 100,000,000 with 6 decimal places of precision". I'm not sure if it matters exactly what we're doing with these numbers, though in this instance is value calculations on financial instruments. We are not governed by any rules of accounting.

I have "done the math". Both a long/integer and a double/epsilon cover the range of values and precision required. As stated in the first sentence, BigDecimal is unacceptably slow for the task. I'm looking for any pros and cons of the two solutions which both could work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `long` and an `int`, with the `long` representing the number of whole units, and the `int` representing the number of billionths.  Such a representation should be fairly easy to work with (especially since the result of adding the `billionths` parts of two numbers can't overflow) and vastly outperform any kind of floating-point representation fancier than `double`.